# Css mask not working on Chrome (Webkit)

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, mask

I have a problem: I made a picture with some layer and wanted to mask them with the mask css property. It works fine on Firefox, whereas on Chrome it doesn't even with the -webkit- prefixe.

Here is the code, note the mask is applied on #plan-1

Maybe Chrome can't make a mask from a jpeg ? :o

```css
body{
            margin: 0;
            background-color:black;
            transform: translateZ(0);
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
            overflow: hidden;
            }
section{
            display: block;
            background-position: center;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            margin: auto;

       }
       
#plan-1{
    mask-image: url('http://felixjely.fr/projet/DGN1/film-couloir/img/piranese/mask-01.jpg'); /*Option de Masque*/
    mask-position:center;
    mask-mode: luminance;
    mask-size: contain;

    -webkit-mask-image: url('http://felixjely.fr/projet/DGN1/film-couloir/img/piranese/mask-01.jpg'); /*Webkit*/
    -webkit-mask-position:center;
    -webkit-mask-size: contain;
    -webkit-mask-type: luminance;


    background:url("http://felixjely.fr/projet/DGN1/film-couloir/img/piranese/03.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;

    z-index: 15;
}

#plan-2{
    background-color:red;
    background-size: contain;

    z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="align">
<section id="plan-1"></section>
<section id="plan-2"></section>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

As WahhabB said, I made a vector based image out of the mask (by vectorise with illustrator/inskape).

Unfortunately, It doesn't work.

```css
body{
            margin: 0;
            background-color:black;
            transform: translateZ(0);
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
            overflow: hidden;
            }
section{
            display: block;
            background-position: center;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            margin: auto;

       }
       
#plan-1{
    mask-image: url('http://felixjely.fr/projet/DGN1/film-couloir/img/piranese/mask-01.svg'); /*Option de Masque*/
    mask-position:center;
    mask-mode: luminance;
    mask-size: contain;

    -webkit-mask-image: url('http://felixjely.fr/projet/DGN1/film-couloir/img/piranese/mask-01.svg'); /*Webkit*/
    -webkit-mask-position:center;
    -webkit-mask-size: contain;
    -webkit-mask-type: luminance;


    background:url("http://felixjely.fr/projet/DGN1/film-couloir/img/piranese/03.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;

    z-index: 15;
}

#plan-2{
    background-color:red;
    background-size: contain;

    z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="align">
<section id="plan-1"></section>
<section id="plan-2"></section>
</div>
```

Comment: Try simplifying this. You only need the most basic minimal viable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve   - something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/d30dpveh/  simple - and without all the other code

Answer (score 8):

This is not currently working in Chrome (Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)). You can see this in the example at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image#Browser_compatibility. In FireFox, the green looks like a star. On Chrome, it is just a box, although it does work if you use the -webkit prefix. However, changing that .svg to your .jpg makes it fail. Take their example:

```
<div id="masked"></div>

#masked {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #8cffa0;
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/12676/star.svg);
}
```

and it works. But replace the url with yours:

```
http://felixjely.fr/projet/DGN1/film-couloir/img/piranese/mask-01.jpg
```

and you will see it doesn't work.

As sheriffderek pointed out, it's always best to start with the simplest possible example.

Comment: Okay so what should I do then ? make a svg mask ? how can I create a svg with the jpeg file I have ? With svg format, can I have some "blurry effect" on edges in order to have a smoother transition ?

Comment: You can create an SVG file from hour jpg using Adobe Illustrator (and perhaps other software). I have done that with your sample file. You can download it from deepwebworks.com/mask-01.svg. You do need to choose the option "ignore white" when you trace the file in Illustrator.

Comment: For different styles of clipping, and browser support, check out the codepen at https://codepen.io/yoksel/full/fsdbu/. I believe that clipping is not meant to support fades.

Comment: When I open my jpg file on Illustrator CC I don't have option to choose.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this

```
-webkit-mask-image: url(YOUR-IMAGE);
```

Answer (score 3):

The mask that the browser expects is not like a Photoshop/Illustrator mask where the white/black corresponds to show/hide. Instead it should be: black/transparent corresponds to show/hide.

Here is the CSS that gets it working with your mask (I turned your mask into a PNG to support transparency, then made the white part transparent):

```
#masked {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #8cffa0;
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl5tc.png);
  -webkit-mask-size: 100px 100px;
  mask-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl5tc.png);
  mask-size: 100px 100px;
}
```

Also note that your mask is much bigger than the masked div's width and height so you have to also specify `mask-size`/`-webkit-mask-size`. My corrected PNG mask image is also attached.

You can also see in the same Mozilla doc page that you mentioned that they used a linear-gradient as a mask and this gradient has two stops: black and transparent: `linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0), transparent);`

[image: Correct PNG-based mask with black corresponding to "show" and transparent corresponding to "hide"]

Answer (score 0):

More of the same of the answers above, but with the original images.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #8f7a66;
}

.el {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 1rem;

    background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1528287942171-fbe365d1d9ac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1200&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ');
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    mask-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/sun.svg');
    mask-size: 100vmin;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-position: center;

    -webkit-mask-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/sun.svg');
    -webkit-mask-size: 100vmin;
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-mask-position: center;

}
```

```html
<div class="el"></div>
```