# Mask CSS does not work properly on Chrome

Tags: javascript, css

Mask CSS does not work properly on Chrome(Version 120.0.6099.199 (Official Build) (64-bit)), but works correctly on Firefox.

Firefox:

Result:
Firefox image with mask

[image]

Applied CSS:

[image]

Chrome:

CSS is applied, but mask does not work as in Firefox

Result:

[image]

Applied CSS:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Expect mask in Chrome to work as in Firefox

full code:

```
import React from "react";

export const ImageElement = (props) => {
    const dataUrl = props.dataUrl
    let maskStyle = {};
    if (props.maskData) {
        maskStyle = {
            WebkitMaskImage: `url(${props.maskData})`,
            WebkitMaskSize: "cover",
            WebkitMaskPosition: "center",
            WebkitMaskRepeat: "no-repeat",
            maskImage: `url(${props.maskData})`,
            maskSize: "cover",
            maskPosition: "center",
            maskRepeat: "no-repeat",
        };
    }

    const width = Math.abs(props.x2 - props.x1);
    const height = Math.abs(props.y2 - props.y1);
    const x = Math.min(props.x1, props.x2);
    const y = Math.min(props.y1, props.y2);

    return (
        <g opacity={props.opacity}>
            <image
                data-element={props.id}
                x={x}
                y={y}
                width={width}
                height={height}
                href={dataUrl}
                style={maskStyle}
                onPointerDown={props.onPointerDown}
                onDoubleClick={props.onDoubleClick}
            />
        </g>
    );
};
```

svg:

```
<svg id="visual" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" width="1920" height="1080" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"><g transform="translate(953.3957094279292 537.5995383517802)"><path d="M286.3 -379.5C370 -333.2 436.1 -248.2 513.8 -136.8C591.6 -25.3 681 112.5 636.9 194.3C592.9 276.1 415.5 301.9 287.1 342.5C158.7 383.1 79.4 438.6 -25.7 473.9C-130.7 509.2 -261.4 524.4 -363.1 475.1C-464.9 425.9 -537.7 312.1 -584.6 185.7C-631.5 59.3 -652.4 -79.7 -619.1 -207C-585.9 -334.4 -498.4 -449.9 -386.1 -487C-273.9 -524 -137 -482.5 -17.8 -458C101.3 -433.4 202.6 -425.8 286.3 -379.5" fill="#000000"></path></g></svg>
```

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44100139/css-mask-not-working-on-chrome-webkit

Comment: The `-webkit-` prefixed rules are not actually being generated in your CSS. Why would depends on what CSS-in-JS solution you are using.

Comment: @subodhkalika yes I have checked, it does not work either

Comment: Hello and Welcome, 
could you please provide a bit more of your Code? html and css? 
Edit: Sorry you already provided the Chrome Version im blind

Comment: Maybe it's the SVG itself that Chrome makes it break

Comment: @adsy it does not work even when ```-webkit-``` rules applied

Comment: OP has chrome version 120, i.e. the first version where the webkit prefix is finally no longer needed

Comment: @Warden330, hello! You can view code now, I edited post

Comment: pointless without knowing what the `props.maskData` actually IS

Comment: @JaromandaX it is path to svg element (<svg></svg>). For example "./assets/7b5c6a5….svg"

Comment: yes, I was actually asking to see the actual SVG you are using - because, in general, using an SVG works - [see this](https://jsfiddle.net/5f0cd2e9/) one using only prefixed and one using only non-prefixed versions, and it works in Chrome (both in chrome 120) - as I said earlier, maybe it's the SVG that breaks chrome

Comment: Why are you thanking me? All I proved is that your question makes no sense because what you claim isn't working actually DOES work

Comment: That SVG breaks chrome, for that. I had no idea why it was not working

Comment: The issue could be the SVG as Jaromanda X pointed out. Chrome handles it a bit different. For Example the masked part has to be black and the part you want to hide has to be transparent. Thats why we need to know how the SVG looks to rule that out as an issue

Comment: I edited post and provided SVG